# How to get time format using country ISO code in android?

Tags: android, time-format

I am working on simple application to show the time in different formate. To show the time I am displaying ISO country code using this ISO code. Can I able to change time in that ISO country format?

I have written code as follows

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = 
    (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
        Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String iso = tMgr.getNetworkCountryIso();
Log.v("Device iso", "=======>" + iso);
String mbNo = tMgr.getLine1Number();
Log.v("mbNo", "=======>" + mbNo);
```

Here I am getting iso as US. Can I show the current system time format in US time format?

I have used Date class to show time as follows

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
systime = df.format(new Date());
```

It is displaying time in HH:MM:SS AM/PM format. I would like to display the above time as US format.

How can I display the time in US or any other format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case I think you could use

```
Date systemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // the current system time
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
Date myDate = df.format(systemDate);
```

Or to use custom format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date myDate = sdf.format(systemDate);
```

if you have a string use parse

```
Date myDate = sdf.parse("29/04/1980 12:30:24");
```

Answer (score 1):

DateFormat has a static [method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29) that can initalize a localized format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to create your own method for US format. Try to create a class and make its super class a `DataFormat` class and simply add your method.